# GLM and saturated models: how do we justify the relation $\hat{\mu}_{i} = y_{i}$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model

Given the saturated generalized linear model $g(\mu) = \eta = \textbf{X}\beta$, where the number of parameters equals the number of observations, why do we have $\hat{\mu}_{i} = y_{i}$? Let's us take an example. Consider that
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
    g(\mu_{1}) \\
    g(\mu_{2})
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_{0} \\
    \beta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_{0} + 2\beta_{1} \\
    2\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{1} \\
    y_{2}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

As it can be seen, such model is saturated because we have the same number of parameters as the number of observations. I do know how to get the desired result $\hat{\mu}_{i} = y_{i}$, but I thought it should be $\hat{\mu}_{i} = g^{-1}(y_{i})$. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I think I am a little bit lost. I know the question is pretty naive, but shouldn't it be $\hat{\mu}_{i} = g^{-1}(y_{i})$?

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I edited the question to include this clarification. Please edit it further as needed to reflect what you're asking, or roll it back, if this is wrong.

Comment: It seems the equation is not true. Take logistic regression, where y is zero or one, but mu is not.

Comment: The example formula in your question is incorrect. The first three terms, which define a link-linear model, are ok but you cannot set it equal to $(y_1,y_2)^T$ unless $g()$ is the identity function. Perhaps that is the source of your confusion. In glm theory, $y$ is on the same scale as $\mu$, not on the scale of the linear predictor.

Comment: @JTH There is no problem with $\hat\mu_i=y_i=1$ for a logistic regression glm. This phenomenon occurs for many datasets -- it's quite common even for models other than the saturated model. For the saturated model, it is always true (although the saturated model is not normally fitted explicitly).

Comment: @user1337 I don't understand your question. $\mu_i = E[y_i]$ is the mean response $\nu = \mathbf{X}\beta$ is the linear predictor. You can't inverse $g$ because it's not always defined on the (non-extended) real line, like with logit(0) in binomial regression or log(0) in poisson regression.